# Slow Performance of xpage while loading a document

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

Below is the code which opens the document.

`var strUrl = "$$OpenDominoDocument.xsp?documentId=" + @Word( action, "$", 1) + "&sec=actions&action=openDocument&aid=" + objUserInfo.getuserId();

return strUrl;`

[image]

Comment: It's a POST request, so did you check your server logs?

Comment: Your question implies loading behaviour was different at a previous time? And “nothing has changed” is never true. Database size, disk fragmentation, cpu use, user activity are never the same. Show some code! (Ans Upgrade your TLS)

Comment: One caveat you could run into is that the document you are opening has a large attachment. When you open the document Domino opens the entire note - and if you have a 100+ MB attachment on that document then you will have to wait for it to load - no matter if you use that data or not.

Comment: Thanks John, the document dosent have any attachments, I had also verified, CPU usage, database size as suggested by Stephan, I will try to upgrade TLS to 1.2 and see if the same behavior.

Comment: Have you tried to debug what's going in during the POST request in order to find possible causes? When you have done that, then come back and update your question with code if you need further help.

Comment: On your Document Datasource on the XPage do  you have "computeWithForm" turned on for load, save, or both?  If so, this can slow down the page, especially if any fields on the underlying form perform @DbLookups.